# which one is better - storing in a list or in a file for temporary storage?

Tags: java, performance

I want to store 100K+ records(a line with some 100 characters) in a temporary storage, which one would be a better option - storing it in file or in a list in term of performance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Performance? `List` by **several orders of magnitude**. No question. `List` would also allow concurrent access. `File` is very very slow compared to memory. The only reason to use a `File` is if the data doesn't fit into memory - in this case a [BTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

A list as in in-memory? So long as you have enough memory to store it then keeping it in a list will always give massively better performance than putting it into a file. The speed-of-access difference between memory and disk is enormous.

The downside of course is that you have a lot more disk space available - so if the list is too large you might need to store it on a hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Storing data in memory (List, HashMap or whatever) is enormously faster. If you run out of memory, before using files, I would suggest you to check out SQlite with a primary index on a column (if you have a unique value for each row). Reading will be faster than sequentially reading a file.